# Prove that $\dim V^*=\dim V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$, and let $V^*$ be the vector space of all linear functions from $V$ to $F$. Show that $\dim V^*=\dim V$.

I was going over this problem with a friend, and he shared this answer with me:
[image]

It all seems correct to me except the span($B^*)$=$V^*$ part. How is this true:
$$
\alpha_1\beta_1+\cdots+\alpha_n\beta_n=\beta_1f_1(\alpha_1v_1)+\cdots+\beta_nf_n(\alpha_nv_n)
$$
I also don't see how this is true:
$$
\beta_1f_1(\alpha_1v_1)+\cdots+\beta_nf_n(\alpha_nv_n)=\beta_1f_1(x)+\cdots+\beta_nf_n(x)
$$
I tried working backwards, but I got stuck:
$$
\begin{aligned}
g(x) &=\beta_1f_1(x)+\cdots+\beta_nf_n(x)\\
&=\beta_1f_1(\alpha_1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n)+\cdots+\beta_nf_n(\alpha_1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n)\\
&=\beta_1f_1(\alpha_1v_1)+\cdots+\beta_1f_1(\alpha_nv_n)+\cdots+\beta_nf_n(\alpha_1v_1)+\cdots+\beta_nf_n(\alpha_nv_n)...
\end{aligned}
$$
So am I missing something, or is that proof wrong?

Comment: Use the definition of $f_i$. It is a linear functional such that for any number $\alpha_i$ one has $\alpha_i=\alpha_i f_i(v_i)= f_i(\alpha_i v_i)=0+\cdots+0+f_i(\alpha_i v_i)+0+\cdots+0=\alpha_1 f_i( v_1)+\cdots+f_i(\alpha_i v_i)+\cdots+\alpha_n f_i(v_n)=f_i(x)$.

Comment: @JankoBracic Thanks for the comment. So where did you get $\alpha_i=\alpha_if_i(v_i)$ from?

Comment: $f_i(v_i)=1$, by the definition of $f_i$, and by the same definition $f_i(v_j)=0$ if $i\ne j$ (the meaning of Kronecker's $\delta_{ij}$).

Comment: @JankoBracic Thank you! That really clears it up for me. I was missing that important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_i = \delta_{ij}$, so $f$ is linear because of $\delta_{ij}$'s linearity.
The $\delta_{ij}$ function basically assumes value $1$ if $i=j$, and $0$ otherwise. So, for instance, $f_2(v_3)= 0$ and $f_5(v_5)=1$. Intuitively, the $f_i$ function on a vector $v$ outputs the $i$-th component of the vector.

So $f_i(\alpha_iv_i)=\alpha_if_i(v_i)$ because $f$ is linear, but since $f_i(v_i)=1$, $f_i(\alpha_iv_i)=\alpha_i$.

For the same reason, $\beta_1f_1(\alpha_1v_1)=\beta_1f_1(x)$ because $f_1(x)=\alpha_1v_1$.

**Alternative proof**

$V^*$ is, by definition, the vectorial space of linear functions $f: V \rightarrow F$, so $V^*=\hom(V,F)$.

If $A$ and $B$ are finite-dimensional vectorial spaces, the following formula holds:

> $\dim_F(\hom(A,B))= \dim_FA\cdot\dim_FB$

So:

$\dim V^*= \dim_F(\hom(V,F))= \dim_FV\cdot\dim_FF= \dim_F V \cdot 1= \dim_F V$

**Beware**: the formula and the result are valid only for finite-dimensional vectorial spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, I am looking for insight into the $\dim B^*=V^*$ proof above.

Comment: I was just showing an alternative way to prove it, I'll clarify your doubts with an edit.